# Return values if all criterias satisfied pl/sql

Tags: plsql

I have a table for example

> User|City
>
> 1|A
>   1|B
>   1|C
>   2|A
>   2|C
>   3|A
>   3|C
>   4|A
>   5|B

I want it to only return if a user is in City A and C not A or C by itself. I.E.

Return

> User|City
>
> 1|A
>   1|C
>   2|A
>   2|C
>   3|A
>   3|C

Comment: I have tried with OR and IN statements but I still get single values A or C.

Answer (score 0):

I have to think this is inefficient with a real data set but this works for your example data.  'tbl' is just the source data.  The real solution starts at the inner select where each row is returned along with the count of the usr value where the city is in the set 'A', 'C'.  Then, select the usr and city where that count is 2, meaning both are matched.  It's a start, anyway.

```
with tbl(usr, city) as (
  select 1, 'A' from dual union all
  select 1, 'B' from dual union all
  select 1, 'C' from dual union all
  select 2, 'A' from dual union all
  select 2, 'C' from dual union all
  select 3, 'A' from dual union all
  select 3, 'C' from dual union all
  select 4, 'A' from dual union all
  select 5, 'B' from dual
)
select usr, city
from ( 
  select usr, city, count(*)
  over (partition by usr) city_count
  from tbl
  where city in ('A', 'C')
)
where city_count = 2;
```

Output:

```
USR|CITY
1|A
1|C
2|A
2|C
3|A
3|C
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of doing it, more efficient because it is not using COUNT function, however does not exactly satisfy the output format needed, although I would think that the output format will still be acceptable because the requirement seems to be retrieving the USRs that satisfy the condition:

```
WITH TBL(USR, CITY) AS (
  SELECT 1, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'B' FROM DUAL
)

SELECT USR_CITY_A.USR, USR_CITY_A.CITY, USR_CITY_B.CITY  
FROM (SELECT USR, CITY FROM TBL WHERE CITY = 'A') USR_CITY_A  
    ,(SELECT USR, CITY  FROM TBL WHERE CITY = 'C') USR_CITY_B  
WHERE USR_CITY_A.USR = USR_CITY_B.USR;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
USR | CITY A | CITY C

1 | A | C   
2 | A | C  
3 | A | C
```